# Populating a single Listview with multiple custom array of objects in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin/Mobile development. I got a task to create a single listview which should populate the objects of two different classes using xamarin.forms.

```
`Class A
{
 string PendingRequestID;
 string PendingRequestStatus;
 string PendingRequest;
}

Class B
{
 String CompletedRequestId;
 String ApprovedByUsername;
 DateTime CompletedTime
}
```

`
above are the two different entities and I need to populate the list of objects of both in single list view. Each object is having its own separate UI layout.

How can i specify multiple ItemSource in a ListView in xamarin.forms?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a property of type `ObservableCollection<object>` for `ItemsSource` on `ListView` and use a data template selector in order to provide item-type based template(s) to `ListView`.

An example can be found [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/)

**EDIT - 1 : Sample code**

```
class MyDataTemplateSelector : Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplateSelector
{
    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {
        // Retain instances!
        this._typeADataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TypeAViewCell));
        this._typeBDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TypeBViewCell));
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        return (item is A) ? this._typeADataTemplate : this._typeBDataTemplate;
    }

    private readonly DataTemplate _typeADataTemplate;
    private readonly DataTemplate _typeBDataTemplate;
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach, data templates are ideal for this scenario.

Comment: @Sharada Gururaj. Thank you for the solution. I will try with this solution now.

Comment: @sharada Gururaj. Its working fine :). How can I add event handler for a control resides in customview cell? Should I need to add it in customviewcell's cs page or in my Maincontentpage cs file? If I have to add it in Maincontentpage's cs file; how to specify it in Customviewcell's xamal?

Comment: It would be easier to use event to command behavior; or tap recognizer command; especially while working through templated controls

Comment: @Sharada Gururaj Thank you. Now I have added gesturerecognizer to my label and added one command parameter. But I am not able to get the command parameter in the code behind of viewcell.   var itemSender = (Xamarin.Forms.View)sender;
            var itemTapGestureRecognizer = (TapGestureRecognizer)itemSender.GestureRecognizers[0];

Comment: If you are using command - how did sender come into picture? Are you using MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign multiple types for `ItemSource`. Therefore, one way is to use a third class as a base class and then derive your `A` and `B` from it. Then use this `C` type as `ItemSource`.

```
Class C{
   ...
}

Class A : C
{
   string PendingRequestID;
   string PendingRequestStatus;
   string PendingRequest;
}

Class B : C
{
   String CompletedRequestId;
   String ApprovedByUsername;
   DateTime CompletedTime
}
```

Note that you will then need to check for the right subtype during runtime whenever you click on an `Item` in the list.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To add, when you define the ObservableCollection which you bind your listview to, it will be ObservableCollection<C> where C is the class your two sub types inherit from.

Comment: @Tait's Thanks for your valuable suggestion, but in my scenario I need to have a different kind of UI layout based on the type.

Comment: @Thavudu Ok, sorry I've missed that info. Then DataTemplateSelector is the way to go. Happy coding!